# send mail using xampp in php

Tags: php, sendmail

I've seen a lot of videos but haven't got a hang of how to `send mail` in php.

I've configured the `smtp port` and `server` along with `php.ini` file and also the `sendmail.ini` file, changed the `auth_username` and `password`. However, the code below still does not work!

```
<?php
    mail('xyz@gmail.com','Hello','Testing Testing','From:abc@gmail.com');
?>
```

Do I need to download anything or change the gmail settings?

Comment: Are you trying to send mails from `localhost`?

Comment: yaa i'm using xampp!but i need the msgs to b sent from my gmail account.i have a internet connection on @Mr.Alien

Comment: see this  tutorials  http://digiex.net/guides-reviews/guides-tutorials/application-guides/544-configuring-php-under-windows-use-gmail-external-smtp-server-ssl.html

Comment: You should really use a proven solution like PHPMailer for this because there are dozens of potential pitfalls you might encounter if you try to do it yourself. Take a look at http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebgmail

Comment: Ghe guys here can explain more, but I have more of a linux experience when it comes to mail, but do not attempt to configure a mailserver without the correct knowledge, because if you miss out one thing, you could fail the,security checks and your outgoing mail would end up in the spam. Use other PHP solutions,which has this configured for you such as PHPmailer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's very easy to configure php.ini for sending e-mails from your server.You just need to configure `php.ini and sendmail.ini` correctly.

First you have to configure sendmail_path in your php.ini file it should have to point to executable sendmail file with proper flags

for example ,
`;sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"` (which is already in your php.ini file need to just remove comment) 
and other assignments to sendmail_path need to be commented.

after configuring php.ini file you need to configure sendmail.ini file ,in that

first `smtp_server=mail.gmail.com` (as you want to use gmail as smtp server), 
second `smtp_port=465` (if not worked try 587), third `auth_username= yourid@gmail.com`
`auth_password=yourpassword`

after this restart your server.

Comment: this is working. maybe you can try to set `smtp_ssl=ssl` if `smtp_ssl=auto` didn't work. but i need to instal apache and mysql then restart. not just running from xampp control panel. i don't know why.

Comment: I have been faffing around with Mercury and this is the solution I needed. Wish I found this yesterday