# PHP message sending script not working

Tags: php, mysql

The following script was supposed to send email if all conditions are met and echo "success". The problem here is it is returning "success" but email is not being sent. I tried my best to figure out the problem but can't figure out as I am new to PHP. So I am looking for any possible help. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance

```
$sql = "SELECT id, username FROM user WHERE email='$e' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $id = $row["id"];
            $u = $row["username"];

        $emailcut = substr($e, 0, 4);
        $randNum = rand(10000,99999);
        $tempPass = "$emailcut$randNum";
        $hashTempPass = md5($tempPass);
        $sql = "UPDATE useroptions SET temp_pass='$hashTempPass' WHERE username='$u' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        $to = "$e";
        $from = "auto_responder@geniusfree.net";
        $headers ="From: $from\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 \n";
        $subject ="GeniusFree Password Reset";
        $msg = '<h2>Hello '.$u.'</h2><p>This is an automated message from GeniusFree. If you did not recently initiate the Forgot Password process, please disregard this email.</p><p>You indicated that you forgot your login password. We can generate a temporary password for you to log in with, then once logged in you can change your password to anything you like.</p><br /><p><a href="http://www.geniusfree.net/passwordreset.php?u='.$u.'&p='.$hashTempPass.'">Click here now to apply the temporary password shown below to your account</a></p><p>If you do not click the link in this email, no changes will be made to your account. In order to set your login password to the temporary password you must click the link above.</p>';
        if(mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers)) {
            echo "success";
            exit();
        } else {
            echo "email_send_failed";
            exit();
        }}
```

Comment: Steps I might take to debug. First, echo all the variables you are sending to the mail function. Do they look correct? Maybe you are sending to a different email address than you think. Second: Does the server you are running on allow php Mail? Some servers have restrictions on what you can and can't use.

Comment: Check the spam. may be your mail will be there.

Comment: mail() function returns true if the email was SENT, it can't tell you whether it was delivered successfully or not.

Comment: Make sure you set a Return-Path so that when the mail is bounced you can see it.

Comment: if you using XAMPP? XAMPP included a fake mail function... this will be not send a mail but returns true

Comment: Are you using the mail server in your host? Or you are using an external mail like google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the MX entry settings. Highest priority is 0. If you are using your mail server in your host. The first entry should be something like this priority number 0 ---> mail.yoursite.com.

Another way to debug this is to use email trace route. You can do it in cpanel.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to configure php to send emails from your server ,if you are running code on your local host machine then you have to configure your php.ini file for sending emails and if code is running on web hosting server then contact them for this issue ,
for configuration details you can refer [send mail using xampp in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003058/send-mail-using-xampp-in-php/16009408#16009408)

if you are using another local server like wamp then you have to separately (download) install sendmail utility on your server.

Hope this works for you

Answer (score -1):

do you run it on the local host? if so , it may does not work there , please test it on the Web Host and let me know the result.

Comment: It's must be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @sectus He doesn't have the required rep to comment.

Comment: when I echo variables releated to mail function they are as they were supposed to be. I mean they are what i expected.