# Localhost mail server

Tags: php, ajax, email, localhost

I have created a website and obviously have a 'contact us' page, I am testing my website on localhost using the xampp server. I am using a macbook with OS X. I have a PHP email form, that sends an email using AJAX and not a mail client. But the emails aren't sending and this is because of the PHP email settings on the xampp server. How do I configure this?

I have seen online that it is needed to configure the php.ini file, but my php.ini file doesn't have what needs to be changed such as:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
auth_password=my-gmail-password
force_sender=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
```

or:

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = my-gmail-id@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

or even the whole [mail function] area on php.ini file, i'm not sure if this is because I am using a MAC and not Windows.

So basically any ways to allow emails to be sent using xampp server?

Comment: I hope https://shellcreeper.com/enable-send-email-in-xampp/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003058/send-mail-using-xampp-in-php might be helpful to you

Comment: @NikunjSoni they both mention the php.ini file, as I mentioned in my question I do not have the code mentioned in my php.ini file

Comment: John Conde please do not mark this as a duplicate without reading my question, as you can see the question you stated does not answer mine.